# Leaflet distinguishing sublayers within one GeoJSON layer

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

I would like to have more than one layer within one existing GeoJSON layer.

I found some example here:

http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/sports/sports.html

which refers to one .json file and afterwards the features are collected from the properties.

I was trying on my code do something more simple, as I want to have the same colour, but only smaller radius of my icon.

My GeoJSON code looks like this:

```
 var sitec = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
        features: [
            {
             type: "Feature",
             "properties": {
                 "Title": "Sitec IS",
                 "Head": "7400 Beach Drive",
                 "Description": "Gavin Sinclair",
                 "Value":2
        },
            "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
            0.16964435577392578,
            52.29220753602784
                ]
                  }
                    },
 {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
"Title": "JHG",
    "Head": "Shortstanton sidings",
"Description": "Conor Murphy",
"Value":1,
"URL": "<a href='https://www.johnhenrygroup.co.uk/' target='blank'>JHG</a>",
"Pict": "image.png"
 },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      0.05458831787109375,
      52.29163006501503
    ]
  }
 }
              ]
        };
```

and what I would like to achieve - set the file icon size based on the propeerties.Value   but keep it in the same group.

My marker customisation looks like this:

```
var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
radius: 8,
fillColor: "#ff7800",
color: "#000",
weight: 1,
opacity: 1,
fillOpacity: 0.8
};
```

and again, I would like to have everything the same, apart from radius, so just in case I set:

```
var geojsonMarkerOptions3 = {
radius: 2,
fillColor: "#ff7800",
color: "#000",
weight: 1,
opacity: 1,
fillOpacity: 0.8
};
```

My code looks as follows:

```
 var sitis = L.geoJSON(sitec, {
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
feature.properties.myKey = feature.properties.Title + ', ' + 
 feature.properties.Head
feature.properties.Value
label = String(feature.properties.Title)
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions).bindTooltip(label, 
  {permanent: true, direction: "center", className: "my- 
  labels"}).openTooltip(); 
  return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions3);  
},
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup("<h1><u><font color='red'>"+feature.properties.Title+"</h1></u></font><h2>Address: "+feature.properties.Head+"</h2><p>"+feature.properties.Description+"</p><p> Website:"+feature.properties.URL+"</p><br><center><img src='images/" + feature.properties.Pict + " ' style='width:200px;height:300x;'>");

  }
    })
    .addTo(map);
```

Map remains the same and console says nothing.

Does anyone knows how to do it? Or shall I write all this stuff separately, creating sth like completely new layer?

[image]

Comment: You can hardly expect somebody will answer your question if you don't even bother to react in any way to answer to your previous question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340499/displaying-selected-layers-depending-on-zoom-in-leaflet/341258#341258

Comment: I missed your previous answer and tried it now, regarding to that post. Now I upvoted, because everything is perfect!

Comment: You might need a secretary to help you deal with all your questions :-)

Comment: This is not an answer for my query. Everyone is learning. But regarding to your sentence, who knows :) Shall I start looking for someone :D

Comment: Small radius at what condition/property from GeoJSON layer?

Comment: Basically I set a property called: Value in the geoJSON file. This is the property, that I would like to distinguish, remain another stuff the same. It's like the same legend feature, but smaller.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer for this query.

As per the problem in the link below:
[Leaflet GeoJSON style function feature only colors one GeoJSON feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/161914/leaflet-geojson-style-function-feature-only-colors-one-geojson-feature/161935)

we must set the style of our geoJSON layer provided.

So we must catch the proper data from feature.properties, which is unique or at least one of few others, different.

Our code should look like this:

```
var sitis = L.geoJSON(sitec, {
//----------------------------- geoJSON style ------------------
   style: function(feature) {
    if (feature.properties.Value === "1") {
    return {
        fillColor: "#ff7800",
        radius: 8
        };
    }
    if (feature.properties.Value == "2") {
    return {
        radius: 4
        };
    }
},
 //-----------------------------geoJSON style code -------------------
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
feature.properties.myKey = feature.properties.Title + ', ' + feature.properties.Head
label = String(feature.properties.Title)
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions).bindTooltip(label, 
 {permanent: true, direction: "center", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
//https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245621/how-to-label-geojson-points-in-leaflet
   },
       onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup("<h1><u><font color='red'>"+feature.properties.Title+"</h1> 
</u></font><h2>Address: "+feature.properties.Head+"</h2> 
 <p>"+feature.properties.Description+"</p><p> Website:"+feature.properties.URL+"</p> 
 <br><center><img src='images/" + feature.properties.Pict + " ' 
  style='width:200px;height:300x;'>");
        layer.on({                          // mouse hover features
            mouseover: function () {
                this.setStyle({
                    'fillColor': '#b45501',
                });
            },
            mouseout: function () {
                this.setStyle({
                    'fillColor': '#ff7800',
                });
            }

        });
 }
    })
    .addTo(map);
```

it works even if we have 
     var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
    //radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#ff7800",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
     };

above, however having the `geojsonMarkerOptions` set above, we can refer our layer style to one parameter only, which in this case is `radius`, alternatively you can put `fillColor` too.

This is analoguous work to the leaflet chloropleth issue, explained here:
https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/[image]

Comment: Why do you accept your answer?

Comment: I might have done it accidentally. I see 0 points and grey thick next to it, so it has been reverted to the initial it looks like.

Comment: Accepting the answer shows others that the question is solved and will remove it from the list of unanswered questions.